# grep macOS matching error

Tags: regex, bash, macos, grep

I'm trying to create a backup script that gets a page HTML with `curl` and then creates a text file with all pdf urls from the HTML page. I'm using grep to archive this, however it is matching all content of the page (except for line breaks). The command I'm running is the following:

`grep -io -e "http:\/\/example\.com\/files\/.*[.pdf|.epub]" page.html`

The urls I'm trying to match are similar to:
`http://example.com/files/all/january/file 1 from user 1 [1983].pdf` or 
`http://example.com/files/2018/january/file 1 from user 22 [2018].epub`

The regex works just fine when testing with online tools.

Any clues?

Notes:
I'm using the brew installation of grep (ggrep) version:
`ggrep (GNU grep) 3.1`

Comment: Can you give us a url of a page you're testing this on?

Comment: Why `[.pdf|.epub]` and not `(\.pdf|\.epub)`?

Comment: @minseong, can't .. it's an internal page.

Comment: @horcrux for some strange reason, (pdf) just don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
grep -ioE 'http:\/\/example\.com\/files\/.*?\.(pdf|epub)'
```

should work right?

Note your provided pattern doesn't match HTTPS urls or `//example.com/...` (inferred protocol?) urls.

Also your pattern will falsely match urls with weird extensions, `.pdffoo` or `.epubs`.

I assume you know the format of urls you're trying to extract.

Pretty sure the above pattern does what you want, as you've laid out in your question.

Comment: Thanks, but, I got the same behaviour... matches everything. I think the problem is related to the `.*`. I tried with `[a-zA-Z0-9 .,-/'’()]*[.pdf|.epub]` and it works partially.. can't find a way to match the "[2018]" except from using .*.

Comment: @JefersonSantos oh, then add a `?` after the asterisk // check edit

Comment: Interesting.. It works perfectly on BBEdit using grep-mode.. but grep keeps matching the whole paragraph which contains the "true" match.

Comment: @JefersonSantos can you provide a sample input? And expected output?

Answer (score 0):

The square bracket syntax is for character sets, not for grouping. You also don’t need to escape the forward slashes:

```
grep -io -e "http://example\.com/files/.*\(\.pdf\|\.epub\)" page.html
```

The backslashes before the brackets and the pipe are required because grep uses Basic Regular Expressions by default. I’ve added backslashes before the periods in the extension so that they don’t match any character.